# How to configure service reference to point to Https, with MutualSSL setup?

Tags: wcf, ssl, https

In my project I recently changed my `WCF` service to use `Https`. It is configured to be a mutual ssl setup and the client and server certificates are both installed appropriately. Server side looks fine and even started fine in the browser as shown below. 
[image: WCF_Https]

However, when trying to configure the service reference from the `WPF` client side (service proxy that was previously added and generated). I get a 403 forbidden error code as shown below. Any idea why?

[image]

Here are my configurations.

**WCF Server Side Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" x509FindType="FindByIssuerName" findValue="QuickFire Root Authority" />
          </serviceCredentials>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
      <service name="PushNotification_SignalR_PoC.WCF.PushNotificationService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MutualSslLargeMessageBinding" contract="PushNotification_SignalR_PoC.WCF.IPushNotificationService" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MutualSslLargeMessageBinding" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate"></transport>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**WPF Client Side Config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
  </startup>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WsHttpBinding_IPushNotificationService"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:30:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                 messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647"
                        maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <endpoint address="https://localhost:44367/PushNotificationService.svc"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WsHttpBinding_IPushNotificationService"
          contract="ServiceProxy.IPushNotificationService" name="WsHttpBinding_IPushNotificationService" />
    </client>

    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MutualSslBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="CurrentUser" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" findValue="QuickFire Test Client"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we want to call the service by adding service reference, we should add the MEX endpoint in the service endpoints on the server side. It could exchange metadata of the service over all platforms.
Like below,

```
<services>
      <service name="PushNotification_SignalR_PoC.WCF.PushNotificationService">
        <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MutualSslLargeMessageBinding" contract="PushNotification_SignalR_PoC.WCF.IPushNotificationService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
      </service>
</services>
```

For details,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/how-to-configure-a-custom-ws-metadata-exchange-binding
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: It was an existing service proxy generated when I added the service reference as `Http`, right now I'm changing it to `Https` and the service reference can no longer be updated or configured to point to the new hosted `Https` WCF (gets the error shown above). I did add the `IMetadataExchange` endpoint as advised though.

Comment: I've read somewhere that when adding `Https` service reference, there should be a prompt asking for client certificate, but mine did not. It's Visual Studio 2019 by the way.

Comment: Have you added the MEX endpoint on the server side, and try again?because it takes effect only when we change the server configuration.

Comment: Yes I did, edited my first comment to include that.

Comment: Since you authenticate the client with a certificate, we should establish the trust relationship between the server and the client, install each other’s certificate in the RootCA, we had better use local machine certificate storage. This could ensure the authentication process is performed and the https security works properly.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/transport-security-with-certificate-authentication